# Some Power BI users are unable to view their dashboard without upgrading to pro

Tags: powerbi, microsoft365

Our orginisation has 13 Power BI Free users, however 2 of them are suddenly greeted with a banner that says they must upgrade to pro to continue. This doesn't make sense to me because everyone else on the same license is working fine. Any ideas as to why this could be happening, and if there is a fix I can try before upgrading their licenses?

I have tried unassigning and reassigning the free Power BI license from the M365 tenant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about custom support, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned if it is their own dash board/reports in thier own My Workspace, I'm assuming that is it a shared workspace. Free users cannot view shared items, other workspaces or apps, it may have been the case that they have clicked the free trial of Pro which has now expired. To view any shared items, users need to be assigned a Pro license. Please refer to the Microsoft documentation on what free users can consume. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-features-license-type

Answer (score 1):

There is not fix for it because as a free user they can't share the content. Moreover as a Pro or Premium user they can share content but to view the content, the viewer must have same license.
There is one condition in which free user can view content shared by Pro or PPU

- *Pro and PPU users can share content and collaborate with free users if the content is saved in workspaces hosted in Premium capacity.*
- *Only Power BI Pro users can publish or share content with other Pro users or consume content that's created by other Pro users, unless a Power BI Premium capacity hosts that content.*

[image]

Comment: You can actually choose in the begining if they should PBI pro users, when creating the workspace go to advanced and modify parameters there.